# onclick and function calling using reactjs

Tags: reactjs

when ever i click the student button it should call the function inside that i have called the other component, but i am getting error. what should i do to call other component by onlick .

```
   import React from 'react';
//import s from './style.css';
import Students from './students.js'
require('./style.scss');
class Display extends React.Component {

  function  studentfunction(){
  <Students/>
  };
  render()
  {

    return(
      <div className="container">
      {this.state.clicked ? <Students/>}
      <h1 className="dashboard">Dashboard</h1>
     <table className="table1" >
     <tbody className="tbody1" >
<tr>
    <td ><input  type="button" value="Students" onClick={this.studentfunction} /></td>
    <td> <input type="button" value="Teachers" /></td>

    <td> <input type="button" value="Inbox" /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
   <td> <input type="button" value="Holidays" /></td>
    <td> <input type="button" value="Circular" /></td>

    <td> <input type="button" value="Notifications" /></td>
    </tr>
<tr>
    <td> <input type="button" value="Events" /></td>

      <td> <input type="button" value="Gallery" /></td>

</tr>
</tbody>
    </table>

      </div>
    );
  }
}
export default Display
```

;

Comment: At leasts take the time to correctly format your code, it's a mess.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way is to use `react-router` library. I highly recommend you to follow [the tutorial](https://github.com/reactjs/react-router-tutorial/tree/master/lessons/01-setting-up).

You will get something like this after [setting up react-router in your app](https://github.com/reactjs/react-router-tutorial/tree/master/lessons/01-setting-up).

```
  <Router history={hashHistory}>
    <Route path="/" component={App}/>
    <Route path="/students" component={Students}/>
  </Router>
```

The next step is to use `Link` component from `react-router`.

```
// modules/App.js
import React from 'react'
import { Link } from 'react-router'

export default React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <h1>Your App</h1>
        <ul role="nav">
          <li><Link to="/about">About</Link></li>
          <li><Link to="/students">Students</Link></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

What you need is not an `onClick handler` on the button but a Link to route to the correct component

Try and specify route for Student component

and then use

```
<button type="button"><Link to="/Students">Students</Link>
```

`onClick` expects a function and not a component that is why you get an error